# EaselJS perspective image transformation

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, perspective, easeljs

Is it possible to make perspective image transformation in html5 canvas? I am using EaselJS right now and can't find a solution for my need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't tried the easel.js yet, but every image transformation is done with matrix operations: translate, rotate, skew etc. Looking on the easel.js source code there is a `Matrix2D` class, and the documentation to it: http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/Matrix2D.html. For a perspective transformation you need to use `rotation`, `scaling` and `skewing`. You need to only play with values and test which is best suited for your needs.

Comment: So far it seems that only 2d affine transformations are implemented in most browsers so you can get some kind of isometric perspectives. For real 3d transformations it looks like we'll need to wait a little longer or jump into WebGL. See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp and http://blog.makezine.com/2009/02/23/projective-transformation-and-persp/

Answer (score 3):

To achieve perspective transformation you need an option to translate object in 3D, but as far as CreateJS/EaselJS uses 2D transformation matrix, you can't do it.

But you can achieve similar look & feel if you will play with Skew and Scale on the go.

For example I made card move on the flatness, which gives to card a perspective view:

```js
var aspectRatio = 1.777777777777778;
var canvasHeight, canvasWidth, canvasTop, canvasLeft;
var graphicsLoader;
var stage, frameTick;


var calculateSize = function() {
  if ((window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight) >= aspectRatio) {
    canvasHeight = window.innerHeight;
    canvasWidth = canvasHeight * aspectRatio;
    canvasTop = 0;
    canvasLeft = (window.innerWidth - canvasWidth) / 2;
  } else {
    canvasWidth = window.innerWidth;
    canvasHeight = canvasWidth / aspectRatio;
    canvasLeft = 0;
    canvasTop = (window.innerHeight - canvasHeight) / 2;
  }

  var gameCanvas = document.getElementById('exampleScene');
  gameCanvas.style.width = canvasWidth + "px";
  gameCanvas.style.height = canvasHeight + "px";
  gameCanvas.style.top = canvasTop + "px";
  gameCanvas.style.left = canvasLeft + "px";
};


//load graphics
graphicsManifet = [
    {id: "flatness", src: "https://i.imgur.com/6E1NKLa.png"},
    {id: "card", src: "https://i.imgur.com/CXhpG1X.png"},
];

graphicsLoader = new createjs.LoadQueue(true);
graphicsLoader.loadManifest(graphicsManifet);
graphicsLoader.on("complete", function() {
    initScene();
}, this);


function initScene() {
  
  stage = new createjs.Stage("exampleScene");
  createjs.Ticker.on("tick", frameTick);
  
  //draw
  var flatness = new createjs.Bitmap(graphicsLoader.getResult("flatness"));
      flatness.x = 200;
  
  var card = new createjs.Bitmap(graphicsLoader.getResult("card"));
      card.alpha = 0;
      
  
  stage.addChild(
    flatness,
    card
  );
  
  var animationTime = intervalTime = 800;
 
  
  createjs.Tween.get()
    .wait(0)
    .call(function() {
      movePerspective(card, 280, 10, 0);
      card.alpha = 1;
    })
    .wait(intervalTime)
    .call(function() {
      movePerspective(card, 1530, 10, animationTime);
      card.alpha = 1;
    })
    .wait(intervalTime)
    .call(function() {
      movePerspective(card, 1570, 680, animationTime);
      card.alpha = 1;
    })
    .wait(intervalTime)
    .call(function() {
      movePerspective(card, 230, 680, animationTime);
      card.alpha = 1;
    })
    .wait(intervalTime)
    .call(function() {
      movePerspective(card, 280, 10, animationTime);
      card.alpha = 1;
    }).loop = true;
   
  
  
};


function frameTick(e) {
  stage.update(e);
}

movePerspective = function(object, x, y, time) {
    typeof time != "number" ? time = 1000 : "";
    var scales = {
        y: y,
        scaleX : 0.887073905 + y*0.000142045,   //  this numbers I calculated depending
        scaleY : 0.761221624 + y*0.000284091    //  on perspective angle of flatness board
    };
    var skAspect = 0.00673453853 - y * 0.000000654928977;
    var cardSkewX = (6.5991 - skAspect * x);
    var pointskew = {
        x: x,
        skewX: cardSkewX
    };

    createjs.Tween.get(object).to({
        x: pointskew.x,
        y: scales.y,
        skewX: pointskew.skewX,
        scaleX: scales.scaleX,
        scaleY: scales.scaleY
    }, time, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(3));
};


window.onload = function() {
  window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
    calculateSize();
  });
};

//set framerate
createjs.Ticker.timingMode = createjs.Ticker.RAF_SYNCHED;
createjs.Ticker.framerate = 60;

$(function() {
   calculateSize();
});
```

```css
#exampleScene {
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.createjs.com/createjs-2015.11.26.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="exampleScene" width="1920" height="1080"></canvas>
```

---

Comment: Need help calculating perspective angle of flatness board